# jQuery UI Sortable: How do I prevent a specific list item from being moved?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="line"><a href="#" class="drag">header (do not sort)</a></li>
    <li class="line"><a href="#" class="drag">line one</a></li>
    <li class="line"><a href="#" class="drag">line two</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I prevent the first `li` from being moved?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can specify which items within the `Sortable` are actually sortable. This should do the trick—change the HTML as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li class="line" id="header"><a href="#" class="drag">header (do not sort)</a></li>
    <li class="line"><a href="#" class="drag">line one</a></li>
    <li class="line"><a href="#" class="drag">line two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then when you set up the sortable:

```
$('ul').sortable({ items: '> li[id!=header]' });
```

Answer (score 7):

You can explicitly exclude items (aside by not including them):

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    cancel: ".disable-sort-item"
});
```

Comment: this works really good, but what about when I don't want that the parent element doesn't sort but inside of it I want to sort things?