# Adding unsortable element to the end of a sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to add an element to the end of a sortable list, e.g. I need to add an extra li.

This Li cannot be sortable and must at all times stick to the end of the sortable list. Just like in firefox tabs (there is a + tab at the end).

Any idea how I can achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a class of some sort to that li ('nosort' or something similar) then when you're defining the sortable add the following option:

```
cancel: '.nosort',
```

This will prevent it from being draggable.

Comment: Thanks - that's great, trouble is you can still sort around it. You can't drag the element but you can drag other elements past it. I need it to stick to the far right (last element and not have it shift from that position). Thanks for your time and effort - great help.

Comment: Yeah, there's no straightforward way to do that.  The way I've worked around that limitation in the past is by wrapping my list and the last element in a wrapper element.  It's hacky, but at least it functions. :(

Comment: Using the sortable create and update events I managed to append an li to the end which sticks quite nicely and is visually quite appealing. You can still move an li past it but on update it jumps to the end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Haraldo The correct answer for your question is the one provided by Cas Bloem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that prevents the item from being sortable at all.

```
// cancel: '.nosort', 

// Use this instead
items: 'li[id!=nosort]',
```

Found the solution here:
[jQuery UI Sortable: How do I prevent a specific list item from being moved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006401/jquery-ui-sortable-prevent-item-from-being-moved)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( "#list ul" ).sortable({
      items: "li:not(.non)"
    });
```

And the HTML:

```
  <div id="list">
       <ul>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item again</li>
         <li class="non">Item not sort</li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to achieve what was asked.