# jquery ui sortable disable for one li item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

It is possible do disable jquery ui sortable just for one list item?
Here is the code example:

```
<ul class="sortable">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

For example I will disable sortable when I click item.
Please Help.

Here is the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sortable li').click(function(){
        // Disable sortable for this item.............
    });
});
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)  Can you include your Javascript?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel <- took 5 seconds to find.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery-ui sortable, prevent item from being moved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006401/jquery-ui-sortable-prevent-item-from-being-moved)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006401/jquery-ui-sortable-prevent-item-from-being-moved although @Mahn's comment is an interesting link and should make it somehow in the original QA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude an element from being dragged in sortable list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885665/how-to-exclude-an-element-from-being-dragged-in-sortable-list)

Answer (score 54):

Sure, try something like this:

```
 $(".sortable").sortable({
      items: "li:not(.unsortable)"
    });
 $(".sortable").disableSelection();
```

By using the [items option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items) you can specify the items that can and can't be sorted.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/67rZz/)**

Comment: Its possible to disable when I click the List Item

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: for example $('.sortable li').click(function(){/*disable this item*/});

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to disable a sortable list item by clicking on it? If so that seems like a separate question.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 34):

You can explicitly exclude items (aside by not including them):

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
     cancel: ".disable-sort-item"
});
```

Comment: easiest to implement.

Comment: This is easy but the disabled item could be moved up or down with in the list group. j08691's answer works in all scenarios.

Answer (score 8):

I know, this question is old. but I let you know right answer. How to dynamically make item disabled and enabled by click.
Because I have the same issue at 2016 :D

first of all. 
All what you need to do is set items to the sortable what will be disabled at start. Add parameter what remove disabled items from the list(it needed on first init):

```
var sortable = $("#sortable-sections");
sortable.sortable({
     items: 'li:not(.ui-state-disabled)',
     helper: 'clone',
});
sortable.disableSelection();
```

(bootstrap used in example)

Then just 
add event listener, I used onClick, so example here:

```
sortable.find('li').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-disabled');
    $(this).hasClass('ui-state-disabled') ? $(this).removeData('sortableItem') : false;
});
```

Sortable-item will be sortable only if he have data what called sortableItem so it will make it dynamically disabled, hope it helps someone.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

This question has two similar answers... but their behavior is very different.

Using `cancel`, you can make item *sortable / not-sortable* **dynamically**:

```
$(".sortable_cancel").sortable({ 
    cancel: ".unsortable" 
});
```

Using `items`, you can make item *sortable / not-sortable* but only at **initialization time**:

```
$(".sortable_item").sortable({
    items: "li:not(.unsortable)"
});
```

See the difference in this demo:

```js
$(".sortable_cancel").sortable({
    cancel: ".unsortable"
});
 $(".sortable_cancel").disableSelection();
 
  $(".sortable_item").sortable({
      items: "li:not(.unsortable)"
    });
 $(".sortable_item").disableSelection();
```

```css
.sortable {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.sortable li {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}

li.unsortable {
    background: #999;
    opacity:.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%;">
    <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
        <label><b>Turn ON/OFF Item1 sortable</b></label>
        <ul class="sortable sortable_cancel">
            <li id="list1_toggle">Item1</li>
            <li>Item2</li>
            <li class="unsortable">Item3</li>
            <li>Item4</li>
            <li>Item5</li>
        </ul>
        <button onclick="$('#list1_toggle').toggleClass('unsortable')">Toggle Item1's unsortable</button>
    </div>

    <div style="width:50%; float:right;">
        <label><b>Item1 will remain sortable</b></label>
        <ul class="sortable sortable_item">
            <li id="list2_toggle">Item1</li>
            <li>Item2</li>
            <li class="unsortable">Item3</li>
            <li>Item4</li>
            <li>Item5</li>
        </ul>
        <button onclick="$('#list2_toggle').toggleClass('unsortable')">Toggle Item1's unsortable</button>
    </div>
</div>
```