Jquery ui sortable table row with specific static column
I have a problem with jquery sortable on table. My table goes like this:
<table>
 <thead>
   <th>Number</th>
   <th>Text</th>
   <th>Order</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: fruits">
  <tr class="ui-state-default">
   <td data-bind="text: number"></td>
   <td data-bind="text: fruit"></td>
   <td data-bind="text: order"></td>
  <tr>

And I want this to make sortable, except on the order column, and I have this code, but it's not working
$( function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    items: 'td:not(:nth-child(3))' }
});

For example if I have



Number
Fruit
Order




1
Banana
5


2
Apple
10


3
Peach
15



When I change it, drag the whole row, I want to look like this, the order to remain the same:



Number
Fruit
Order




2
Apple
5


1
Banana
10


3
Peach
15




https://stackoverflow.com/a/53823715/4248328

There is not going to be a good way to do this since you are sorting the Row not the Cells. The row, containing all the cells, will be moved. You could put two Tables side by side and then just Sort the first table.

Consider an alternative method.


$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
});
.sidebyside {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: -1px;
  padding: 0;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div style="width: 400px;">
  <table class="sidebyside" style="width: 66%;">
    <thead>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Text</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: fruits">
      <tr class="ui-state-default">
        <td data-bind="text: number">1</td>
        <td data-bind="text: fruit">Banana</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ui-state-default">
        <td data-bind="text: number">2</td>
        <td data-bind="text: fruit">Apple</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ui-state-default">
        <td data-bind="text: number">3</td>
        <td data-bind="text: fruit">peach</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="sidebyside" style="width: 33%;">
    <thead>
      <th>Order</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: fruits">
      <tr class="ui-state-default">
        <td data-bind="text: order">5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ui-state-default">
        <td data-bind="text: order">10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ui-state-default">
        <td data-bind="text: order">10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
</div>



It will be a bit more work to populate the tables, yet it does achieve what you set out to do.
